# Powerapps import unsuccesfull

Tags: powerapps

After creating a custom entity and choosing the CSV file that I wish to import, Powerapps is showing the Mapping Status as 'Matched'. However when I go to import data from this CSV I receive a 'Import failed' message along with a notification saying 'Your import was unsuccessful' with no further information. Is there anywhere that I can access an error log to show any further details, or does anyone have an idea of how to address this generic error?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you resolved your issue, but With the work that i've done in PowerApps, it likes only excel tables that have been formatted as tables. So you would have to create as a table, make sure that the headers are converted and save as an excel file, not csv.